# Is there a way to cancel fzf by pressing escape

Tags: vim, command-line, fzf, vim-fzf

I have `alias vif='vim $(fzf)` in my `~/.zprofile` and it works great; however, it always opens vim window even if I click `esc` button because I didn't find the file I was looking for. How do I get it to not open `vim` if I press `esc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a shell function, that will allow you to check whether `fzf` exited with a non-zero status. (It exits with status 130 if interrupted with Esc or Ctrl+C.)

```
function vif() {
    local fname
    fname=$(fzf) || return
    vim "$fname"
}

function fcd() {
    local dirname
    dirname=$(find -type d | fzf) || return
    cd "$dirname"
}
```

The `|| return` part will break out early when the return code is non-zero, so `vim` will only be invoked after a successful `fzf` execution.